# How to create icon or widget that reflects status of remote ssh server?

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, icons

I am using sshfs mounted at boot time to sync my laptop with a ssh server. That works great but the server is not always on the LAN the laptop is connected to, so I would like a desktop icon or kubuntu plasma widget that changes colour depending on whether the server is visible. Is that possible?